# Android ActionBar custom behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I created fully custom action bar, removed all native control from there and added button in left side.

This is done in order to get full control over action bar layout.
Now when user clicks on this button i want to grant the same functionality as Native Up button.

In other words i from my button click event i need the same functionality as default code here.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
```

How this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Switch android.R.id.home with the id of the custom button, R.id.menu_button_name.

ActionBar is now being replaced with [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) which gives you more control and customization options than ActionBar. Here are some [examples of what you can do with the Toolbar](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#custom-behaviors) these days.